# How to reference values in a join table for a rails where method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a noob level question.

i've got two models: Patient and Provider joined through a table Chart.

i used the association "has_many :through"  rather than "has_and_belongs_to_many"   because i need to have another column added to the Chart table [called patient_mrn] which i understand that i cannot do with the "has_and_belongs_to_many" scenario.

the Patient model has:

```
    has_many :charts
    has_many :providers, :through => :charts
```

the Provider model has:

```
  has_many :charts
  has_many :patients, :through => :charts
```

and the Chart model has:

```
    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :provider
```

i am trying to call a where method on the Patient model to retrieve all patients with the conditions that:

-the provider_id  in the Chart join table for that patient equals a given value [@exam.provider_id] and

-the patient_mrn in the Chart join table for that patient equals a given value[@exam.patient_mrn].

this is what i came up with to try but it clearly isn't working. Where am i going astray?

```
@patient = Patient.where(:patient.chart[provider_id] => @exam.provider_id,
          :patient.chart[patient_mrn] => @exam.patient_mrn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Joining tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) is what you need to do in order to specify conditions on a model's associated table.  (Look at the section on [specifying conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) for an example of what you're looking to do).

But, in short, you want to join to your `chart` table and specify conditions on that.  Your query should probably look something like:

```
@patients = Patient.joins(:charts).where(:charts => { :provider_id => @exam.provider_id, :patient_mrn => @exam.patient_mrn })
```

This should return all `Patients` whose `chart` has the given `provider_id` and `patient_mrn`.

Comment: Thanks Baron- works great!!!

I forgot to ask how can I add one more AND term to the one with the joins?

Patient.find(:all, :conditions=>['dob = ?', @exam.patient_dob])

Thanks!!!

Comment: Just tack on another `where`: `Patient.joins(:charts).where(:dob => ...).where(:charts => { ... })`